# List of words with irregular pronunciations, with frequency information

Tags: prononciation, lexique

French, specifically fr-FR, has a remarkably consistent orthography.

If you know the rules, then given a written word, one should be able to pronounce it correctly even if you don't know what it means.

There are some exceptions which I'll classify as three types:

1. when you need to know the part of speech: e.g. *-ent* for third person plural verbs
2. when you need to know the context: e.g. poetry, singing, slang, deliberate mispronunciations for comedic or dramatic effect
3. actual exceptions, usually quite minor, like *parasol* where *s* is /s/ vs. /z/, or *aigu* where *ai* is /e/ vs. /ɛ/.

For those of type 3, I'm looking for a **list with word frequency**. Does anyone know of one available?

Comment: The OP is looking for a large list that includes all common words of type 3. Not for a few examples.

Comment: A single s between two vowels is normally /z/, it is doubled when it is pronounced /s/. Words using /e/ or /ɛ/ depend on the accent more than anything else.

Comment: @Unfrancophone - Not in _parasol_ or _tournesol_

Comment: @Unfrancophone - Have changed the example to *parasol*. Thank you mouviciel.

Comment: @mouviciel, that's why I wrote normally, and note that both are compound words and the s is starting the second word.  That still seems regular (but the rule is more complex that what I outlined).

Comment: Moderator notice: I have deleted answers that only mentioned a handful of words. Please note that the question is asking for a **list with frequency information**.

Comment: @Sifu I would disagree. It's distinct. I won't vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Although your statement is true comparatively with English pronunciation, I believe French is much more difficult to pronounce from the written form than, say, Italian or German.

One category you entirely disregard contains spellings with letters that should or shoud not be pronounced: `net` and `un jet`, `une vis` and `un avis`,...

You mention that you are looking for a list of rules and exception, probably you should have a look at the literature about speech synthesis, which may use such a list.